# Typescript/JavaScript- modify the body element in index.html (Angular app)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular app with the following code in index.html:

```
<body data-theme="value1">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

I am trying to modify the value of data-theme from app.component.ts (for example, to change the value from "value1" to "value2").  I already have the logic for what value to use inside app.componenent.ts, so I would like to dynamically set the value from there (instead of writing javascript inside of index.html).  I have played around with injecting the DOCUMENT into app.component.ts, but I'm not finding the right syntax to make this modification.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I can answer my own question.

In index.html:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

In app.component.ts

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
```

inject the document into the constructor

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document)
```

And this is how you modify the body:

```
const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.setAttribute("data-theme", value1);
```